# Android Studio is not detecting my phone for debugging. How to fix it?

Tags: android

My android device is Redmi HM 1S and earlier it used to work earlier. Once I uninstalled the Android Studio and again reinstalled it. Since then, Android Studio is not detecting my device. Please help me fixing this.

Comment: Confirm these steps - MIUI optimization is disabled and Your phone is showing up when you type adb devices in cmd.

Comment: You need adb drivers of your phone. Then check if your developer options is set ON. Only after this, your device can be detected by Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer options in your phone and enable usb debugging.
Once you enable it you can see your see in Android Studio.

For enabling developer option use the steps below.

Step 1: Unlock your phone and go to main Settings on your Xiaomi devices.

Step 2: Scroll down to find About phone and tap on it.

Step 3: Locate Miui Version and tap seven times on it.

Answer (score 0):

After you have activated the developer mode by Clicking on

> MIUI version : 5 times

Go to

> Additional Settings --> Developer Mode
>
> Turn on USB Debugging and turn off MIUI optimization

your device should be ready for debugging